# ACL Component is not working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, acl

i am having problems using ACL Component:

when I save an User in my add action I run this code:

```
        $aro = $this->Acl->Aro;
            $aro->create();
            $aro->save(array(   
                'alias' => $this->request->data['User']['username'],
                'parent_id' => $this->request->data['User']['role_id'],
                'model' => 'User',
                'foreign_key' => $this->request->data['User']['id'],
        ));
```

But it causes error, saying create method doesnt exist.

Which is the better way to implement ACL?

I was trying with above code and parentNode and bindNodes's code, but I'm struggling about it...

Comment: Do you really need ACL? Or can it also be declared statically in a file as well as dynamically in the controller etc?

Comment: I know its complicated for newbies users, but I am really interesting in using it. Is there any tutorial for CakePHP 2? I found some stuff but is for previous versions

Comment: Interesting != A good reason. If you don't have a good reason to use ACL, don't do it. It's a horrible idea to use a totally overkill piece of functionality if you only need basic action/role based access. Rather try sth lightweight like [this](http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/12/18/tinyauth-the-fastest-and-easiest-authorization-for-cake2/).

Comment: @mark Its OK. I am doing a plugin to manage role-based users. Do you think with only Auth or your suggestion TinyAuth it will work? My intention is creating role-based permissions for users dynamicly

Comment: Well, I guess you could integrate it with both. Tiny would work action based only, whereas the core ACL - in theory - would also support row based access (which I never used as I use the controllers for this then).

Comment: @mark I will folloW your suggestions. i will begin with (your?) TinyAuth, and I will see if its enough. I accept your answer as valid! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the '`parent_id`' should be the id of the **aro node referencing the role** in the ARO table, **NOT the role_id** itself. You can get it by doing something like:

```
$parentId = ClassRegistry::init('Aro')->field('id', array('model' => 'Role', 'foreign_key' => $this->request->data['User']['role_id']));
```

However, I would recommend attaching the AclBehavior to the User and Role models to automatically update the ARO table for you. Follow [this section](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html#acts-as-a-requester)  carefully in the book. It is a direct analogy of what you are doing - simply replace `Group` in the tutorial to `Role`. Using the behavior will also help you use the AclBehavior::node() method which will help you get node references easily without doing finds on the Aro and Aco models directly.